# How to implement Area.contains(Area)?

Tags: java, geometry, polygon, area

There are 2 areas (`java.awt.geom.Area`) **area1** and **area2**. I need to verify if **area2** is inside **area1**? (**area1** contains **area2**).

I have tried:

```
areaDelta = (Area)area1.clone();
areaDelta.add(area2);
return areaDelta.equals(area1);
```

But it doesnt always work as it should (If the bounds of **area2** are on the bounds of **area1**, it returns true, should return false).

In fact I have 2 polygons (java.awt.Polygon) and I need the Polygon.contains(Polygon) method, may be this can be easier then for areas.

Any ideas?

Polygons can be convex and non-convex.

Comment: Check for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833802/check-if-polygon-is-inside-a-polygon
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017872/determining-polygon-intersection-and-containment

Comment: can you get away with a bounding rectangle check?

Comment: Found it - how to do It without any additional libraries: do the line intersection check for each pair of polygon's lines, It isn't hard to do with standart java library. But It isn't the most perfomance solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have Polygon.contains(Point), you can achieve what you need by testing if every point of your second polygon is inside the first polygon (I dream of a JDK version which would implement every basic need of a programmer, like .NET).

**EDIT:** To handle concave polygons, you first need to split your polygons into convex ones, then you'll be able to properly use the method mentioned above. I used two different polygon decomposition algorithms in [one of my applications](http://code.google.com/p/box2d-editor/), and I would suggest you to look at their code:

- [Bayazit Decomposer](http://code.google.com/p/box2d-editor/source/browse/#hg%2Feditor%2Fsrc%2Faurelienribon%2Fbodyeditor%2Fearclipping%2Fbayazit)
- [Ewjordan Decomposer](http://code.google.com/p/box2d-editor/source/browse/#hg/editor/src/aurelienribon/bodyeditor/earclipping/ewjordan)

Comment: It doesn't work because the polygons can be both convex and non-convex. I've thought about it. About a note - thank you, but I know it, someone has edited my post...

Comment: It works if you also check that every vertex of the first polygon is outside the second polygon.

Comment: You can also convert your polygons into convex ones, then the test is trivial. See my edition.

Comment: Thank you, but it means a full rewrite of standart library (there is no decomposion function) or using additional libraries. Anyway, it works, what I needed. I'll try to link this with java's standart one.